# R: how to find x given the value of qnorm(x)=-2

Tags: r, normal-distribution

Given the value of qnorm(x)=-2, how to find x using R?
I'm trying to solve the power 1-beta from the value of qnorm(1-beta).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pnorm` function serves as the inverse for `qnorm`. Ergo

```
> pnorm(qnorm(0.5))
[1] 0.5
```

So to your question

```
> pnorm(-2)
[1] 0.02275013
> qnorm(0.02275013)
[1] -2
> 1 - pnorm(-2)
[1] 0.9772499
```